# Структурированный ответ от salt minion

Tags: saltstack

Есть N количество машин с salt minion под управлением windows 7. При выполнении какой-либо команды они отвечают  хаотично. Как сделать, что бы они отвечали в нужном мне порядке ?

Comment: т.к. minion-ы не взаимодействуют друг с другом, они не смогут ответить вам в **нужном вам порядке**.

Comment: А если зайти с другой стороны, сервер взаимодействует с minion-ами пусть он выводит ответы в нужном порядке. Это можно сделать как то ?

Comment: с другой стороны два варианта: добавить в программу требуемую функциональность (благо там всё на питоне) или самому отсортировать информацию, выдаваемую программой.

Comment: третий вариант: получить список minion-ов, отсортировать его требуемым образом, и опрашивать minion-ов по списку, по одному за раз.

Comment: А как перенаправить весь вывод допустим в MySQL . И там уже играться запросами как мне удобно